# p:confirmDialog message not refreshed after f:setPropertyActionListener

Tags: primefaces, dialog, commandlink

I have a datatable and on each row there is a `commandLink`. On click of `commandLink` I set the row object to a property of baking bean using `f:setPropertyActionListener` tag.

When I debut I can see setter of property has been called and correct value is getting passed. On `commandLink oncomplete` I also have a call to open `ConfirmDialog`, which shows some values from selected row to user before confirming the action.

The problem is that `ConfirmDialog` is not showing the latest value selected.

```
<p:commandLink id="divAdj" 
               styleClass="commandlink" 
               value="Confirm" 
               oncomplete="confirmation.show()" 
               update="@form" 
               process="@this">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{corporateActionBean.selectedCARecord}"
                                 value="#{dividendRecord}"/>
</p:commandLink>


<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" 
                 header="Confirm Corporate Action #{corporateActionBean.selectedCARecord.umcaType}" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the dialog in same `<h:form>` element? Looks like the `update="@form"` attribute is causing the problem. Try to put table and dialog in the same form and set `update="confirmDialog"`.